# customer callback OR standard function in Codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, callback

I'm validating a Codeigniter form with the following rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('friend1', $this->lang->line('friend1'), 'required|callback_valid_email_or_default[friend1]');
```

I would like my callback function to return `TRUE` if the value of the field is the default one (i.e. "Email 1") **or** if the email is a valid one. This way, the validation will pass if the email is correct or if the value hasn't been changed.

My current callback looks like this:

```
public function valid_email_or_default($input_value, $field){
     if ($input_value == $this->lang->line($field)) {
//Here I need to add something like ||valid_email
         return TRUE;
     }
     else {
         return FALSE;
     }
}
```

I would like to re-use the `valid_email` rule from CI.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a proper way to call `valid_email` so I solved it using the native [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) PHP function:

```
filter_var($input_value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```